# How to delete specific key from all the child nidra in fire base android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete child "1" from all the months and all the dates simultaneously..

here is my database

[image]

Comment: Hi, have you tried something that we can continue on?

Comment: Is `1A` a direct child of your root node? Please add a more detailed database schema and please also respond with @AlexMamo